# Show that $f = \frac{\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^2}$ is a $C^1$ function.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I've made a proof attempt at the following question but I'm not sure if it's correct. It's a long post, but I'm mainly interested in some broad feedback, is the approach in general correct and is there room for improvement, parcticularly shorter ways to prove it. Thanks!

We look at the function $f\colon  \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^2} & \textrm{als } x \neq 0, \\
y^2 & \textrm{als } x = 0. 
\end{cases}
$$
I need to show that $f$ is a $C^1$ function (continuously differentiable), and calculate $f'$.

This is my attempt:

Firstly we calculate the partial derivatives $D_1f(x,y), D_2f(x,y)$. For this, we define the functions $g_1, g_2\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $g_1(t) = f(t,y)$ and $g_2(t) = f(x,t)$. It follows that
$$
D_1f(x,y) = g'_1(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g_1(x+h)-g_1(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}
$$
and 
$$
D_2f(x,y) = g'_2(y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g_2(y+h)-g_2(y)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x,y+h) - f(x,y)}{h}
$$
Firstly we assume that $x \neq 0$. Then we can use the standard method of differentiation to find the partial derivatives, using the quotient rule. We compute: 
\begin{align*}
D_1f(x,y) = g'_1(x) & = \frac{\frac{2xy^2}{1+x^2y^2} \cdot x^2 - \log(1+x^2y^2) \cdot 2x}{x^4} \\
& = \frac{\frac{2x^2y^2}{1+x^2y^2} - 2\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^3} \\
& = \frac{2(x^2y^2-(1+x^2y^2)\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^3(1+x^2y^2)},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
D_2f(x,y) = g'_2(y) & = \frac{\frac{2x^2y}{1+x^2y^2} \cdot x^2}{x^4}
= \frac{2y}{1+x^2y^2}. 
\end{align*}
Now suppose $x = 0$. Notice that $D_2f(x,y)$ is defined for $x = 0$, and is equal to $2y$. This corresponds with the fact that 
$$
D_2(0,y) = g_2'(y) = \frac{\partial f(0,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial y} = 2y. 
$$
We can also calculate this straight from the definition easily: 
\begin{align*}
D_2(0,y) & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0,y+h)-f(0,y)}{h} \\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(y+h)^2 - y^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{y^2 + 2yh + h^2 - y^2}{h}  \\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2yh + h^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} 2y + h = 2y. 
\end{align*}

Finally, we have to calculate $D_1(0,y)$ from the definition because it is undefined in our earlier calculation, and the limit involves both, terms $f(x,y)$ with $x = 0$ and with $x \neq 0$. We use here the expansion $\log(1+t^2y^2) = t^2y^2 - \frac{t^4y^4}{2} + O(|t^6y^6|)$. 
We compute: 
\begin{align*}
D_1(0,y) & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t,y) - f(0,y)}{t} \\
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{\log(1+t^2y^2)}{t^2} - y^2}{t} \\
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log(1+t^2y^2) - t^2y^2}{t^3} \\
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2y^2 - \frac{t^4y^4}{2} + O(|t^6y^6|) - t^2y^2}{t^3} \\
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{-\frac{t^4y^4}{2} + O(|t^6y^6|)}{t^3} 
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{-ty^4}{2} + \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{O(|t^6y^6|)}{t^3} = 0. 
\end{align*}

We now use the theorem that $f$ is $C^1$ (continuously differentiable) iff all of its partial derivatives exist and are continuous. Notice that for $x \neq 0$, they are continuous, because they are quotients of continuous terms. We prove that they are continuous in $(x,y)$ with $x=0$ as well. So we need to show that $\lim_{(x,y') \to (0,y)} D_1f(x,y') = D_1f(0,y) = 0$. We use here the expansion $\log(1+x^2y^2) = x^2y^2 + O(|x^4y^4|)$. We compute: 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y') \to (0,y)} D_1f(x,y') & = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{2x^2y^2}{1+x^2y^2} - 2\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^3} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{2x^2y^2}{1+x^2y^2} - 2(x^2y^2 + O(|x^4y^4|))}{x^3} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{2x^2y^2 - 2x^2y^2(1+x^2y^2)}{1+x^2y^2} + O(|x^4y^4|))}{x^3} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{- 2x^4y^4}{1+x^2y^2}}{x^3} + \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{O(|x^4y^4|)}{x^3} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{- 2xy^4}{1+x^2y^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-2y^4}{\frac{1}{x}+xy^2} = 0. 
\end{align*} 
For $D_2$ we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y') \to (0,y)} D_2f(x,y') & = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2y}{1+x^2y^2} = 2y = D_2f(0,y). 
\end{align*}
Thus we conclude that $f$ is $C^1$ since both partial derivatives are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The derivative is then given by 
$$
f'(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2(x^2y^2-(1+x^2y^2)\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^3(1+x^2y^2)} & \frac{2y}{1+x^2y^2}
\end{bmatrix}
& \textrm{if } x \neq 0, \\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2y
\end{bmatrix}
& \textrm{if } x = 0. 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Here is a shorter way.  The only questionable point is $(0,0)$.  We can write for $|xy|<1$ $$\frac{\log(1+x^2y^2)}{x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2(n-1)}y^{2n}}{n}$$which is analytic in the region of convergence.

Comment: @MarkViola I think the whole axis $x=0$ is questionable, not merely the origin.

Comment: @A.Γ. This is true, however you can still use power series development for $\vert xy \vert <1$.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on this? I don't see why $(0,0)$ is the only questionably point, and what analytic in the region of convergence means, and why you use $|xy| < 1$.

Comment: Yet another possibility: define $f(t)=\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t^2}$, $t\ne 0$, and zero when $t=0$, and prove that it is $C^1$. Then the original function $f(xy)\cdot y^2$ will be $C^1$ as well.

Comment: @A.Γ. The differentiability of the function of interest is evident for all $x \ne 0$.  Is that the meaning of your comment?

Comment: That makes sense. So from that I take it that the product and composition of $C^1$ functions is again $C^1$? Also, is it easier to show that this new function is $C^1$ you reckon?

Comment: @Sigurd Yes, composition of $C^1$ is $C^1$. I wrote wrong about defining the function at $t=0$, it must be one, of course.

Comment: @MarkViola It was just a somewhat pedantic reaction on the statement "the only questionable point is $(0,0)$", which I suggested to correct as "the only questionable points are those on the $y$-axis".

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  But the salient feature of the comment prevails.